# JQ getting compile error response from query

Tags: syntax, jq

I would like to ask for your guidance for newbie like me on testing query on a sample file. I'm getting  compile error while testing it. Please advice on what is needed to adjust.

JSON FILE --> sample.json

```
    {
    "lambda": {
        "apple": [
            {
                "type": "fruit",
                "color": "red",
                "shape": "round",
                "cron": "0/10 * * * ? *"
            }
        ],
        "orange": [
            {
                "type": "fruit",
                "color": "orange",
                "shape": "round",
                "cron": "0/15 * * * ? *"
            }
        ],
        "apple-cider": [
            {
                "type": "juice",
                "color": "pink",
                "shape": "none",
                "cron": "0/30 * * * ? *"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm getting this *jq: 1 compile error* message when I tried to get data from **apple-cider**

```
# jq -r ".lambda."apple-cider"[].shape" test.json
jq: error: cider/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.lambda.apple-cider[].shape
jq: 1 compile error
```

Comment: In future, please do not change a question after it has been answered accurately, if the change renders that answer obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it worked with this command

```
jq -r '.lambda."apple-cider"[].type' test.json
```

Answer (score 2):

[This response answers the Q as originally posted.  Before the modification, the input was a stream of JSON objects.]

The reason you're seeing multiple outputs is that your input is a stream, and your filter is applied to each item in the stream.

So it looks like you should modify your filter, e.g.

```
.apple.color // empty
```

Regarding the key "apple-cider" -- since it has a special character ("-"), you cannot use the abbreviated syntax.  Whichever version of jq you have, you can use the unabbreviated form: `.["apple-cider"]`; you might also be able to use the form:

```
."apple-cider"
```

Comment: Hi peak, sorry I'm not getting the point, can you share on hw would it be tested in command line?

Comment: I was able to clear the null issue, when I modified the json file to new format
I'm just getting an issue while trying to get date from apple-cider

Comment: I got the issue cleared by using the command :-) =====>

jq -r '.lambda."apple-cider"[].type' test.json